# how to access dom elements from gwt unit testcase?

Tags: unit-testing, gwt

my question is:
how can I access dom elements from gwt unit testcase?

I have only a static html with a link:

```
<a href="#" id="my_button">jjj</a>
```

When I do

```
public void testButton() {
    Element elm = Document.get().getElementById("my_button");
    assertNotNull(elm);
}
```

I'll get a RuntimeException (test failed) because `elm` is `null`.

What's wrong? Am I missing any init call...?

Answer (score 1):

Unit tests in GWT do not use your application's host page; they use a (or junit-standards.html) from the `com.google.gwt.junit.JUnit` module, which is almost empty.

You have to "create" the environment your test runs in (in `gwtSetup` or at the beginning of your test method).

Comment: any pointers about how to setup the test environment to use a host page that I have designed ?